# Different Configuration for the_excerpt()

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I am creating a basic website with wordpress. here i making some layout for different pages. 
In different page, i will show different post type. and i need different configuration `the the_excerpt()` function. since in service page i need to show 150 character or 40 words of post content but in blog page i need to show 250 character or 100 word of post content. and then need to show button or only read more text.
i tried  the following but it changes the function globally:

```
function wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 10;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
function wpdocs_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return sprintf( '<a class="read-more" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
        get_permalink( get_the_ID() ),
        __( 'Read More', 'textdomain' )
    );
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpdocs_excerpt_more' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should simply use the wp_trim_words function to achieve what you want. Simply pass the get_the_excerpt value in it.

`<?php $trimmed = wp_trim_words( $text, $num_words = 55, $more = null ); ?>`

Comment: Thank you @jpburn I wanted more specified solution. its like raw php, searching some with wp.